# How to optimize the animation?

Tags: java, android, android-animation, smoothing

I have a `collapsingToolbarLayout` and I want to make some animation, while user expands/collapses the view. I've added some animation in `addOnOffsetChangedListener`, but the problem is that the animation is not smooth. E.g. on Collapse `imageview` has to scale out, then alpha. Also it has not to change it's position, so for this I've used `translationY`. Ok let me show my code. I'm using `dataBinding`.

```
binding.appbar.addOnOffsetChangedListener((abLayout, offset) -> {
        // Scale out the image and alpha.
        float scale = 1 - ((float) Math.abs(offset)/abLayout.getTotalScrollRange());
        binding.image.setTranslationY(Math.abs(offset));
        binding.image.animate().scaleX(scale).scaleY(scale).alpha(scale);

        if (Math.abs(offset) == abLayout.getTotalScrollRange()) {
            binding.labelNewsTitleToolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            binding.labelNewsTitle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else if (Math.abs(offset) < abLayout.getTotalScrollRange()) {
            binding.labelNewsTitle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            binding.labelNewsTitleToolbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        if (offset == 0)
            binding.image.animate().scaleX(1.0f).scaleY(1.0f).alpha(1.0f);
    });
```

How can I optimize it to make more smooth? When I collapse the view faster, the image can't animate in time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a thread? On the overrided `run()` method try to call it 60 times per second. I used the code below:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    double firstTime;
    double lastTime = System.nanoTime() / 1000000000d;
    double passedTime;
    double unprocessedTime = 0;
    deltaT = 0;
    while (running) {
        render = false;
        firstTime = System.nanoTime() / 1000000000d;
        passedTime = firstTime - lastTime;
        lastTime = firstTime;

        unprocessedTime += passedTime;
        frameTime += passedTime;
        //Frame time must be around 0.0166667
        if (frameTime <= 0.016667 && frameTime >= 0.01666) {
            deltaT = frameTime;
        }

        while (unprocessedTime >= UPDATE_CAP) {
            unprocessedTime -= UPDATE_CAP;
            render = true;

            if (frameTime >= 1d) {
                frameTime = 0;
                fps = frames;
                frames = 0;
            }
        }

        if (render) {
            //Render 
            //Call here the animation
            panel.repaint();
            frames++;
        }
    }
}
```

Inside the `if(render)` statement call your animation method.
This worked well for me, hope it does the same for you.

Comment: How can I wrap my code in thread? I need to add `offsetChangeListener()` in another thread?

Comment: No need to add another Thread. Just add `implements Runnable` or `extends Thread` on your animation class. Implements the `run()` abstract method and copy my code, call the animation method inside the `if(render)` statement and start the Thread on your main with the method `start()`. Anyway follow this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html) or this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) to learn more about Threads in java.

Comment: Yeah I know, but also you have fields, that are not initialized in your example, e.g. running or UPDATE_CAP or panel.repaint();

Comment: Yeah, you right, my bad. The update cap i used is this `private final double UPDATE_CAP = 1d / 60d;` which is also around 0.0166 (1 / 60 Frame) and the running boolean field is just a variable that is `true` as long as you want the thread to run.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you change `alpha` and `scale` values directly (without animation)? Your `scale` variable depends on offset, and it changes from 0 to 1, so I think everything will look smooth.

```
binding.appbar.addOnOffsetChangedListener((abLayout, offset) -> {
    float scale = 1 - ((float) Math.abs(offset)/abLayout.getTotalScrollRange());
    binding.image.setTranslationY(Math.abs(offset));
    binding.image.setScaleX(scale)
    binding.image.setScaleY(scale)
    binding.image.setSAlpha(scale);
    ....
}
```